# Python closed loop control

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have created a tkinter app that moves a motor connected to a stage. I implemented a "go to position" function and it works, I just want to know if there is a better way to do it and if this is good practice or not.

Here is my code:

```
def go_to_position_x(target):
    global go_x
    target = float(go_to_x.get()) # Input from tkinter app
    go_x = True
    while go_x:
        window.update() # keep position updated in the GUI
        position_x = read_once() # gets float value rounded to 2 places
        if position_x < target and go_x == True:
            stop_x_reverse(target)
            run_x(target)
        elif position_x > target and go_x == True:
            stop_x(target)
            run_x_reverse(target)
        elif position_x == target and go_x == True:
            stop_x_reverse(target)
            stop_x(target)
            print("move x done")
            go_x = False
            break
        else:
            stop() # stops all motors and sets go_x to False
            print("got to else and stop")
            # reset go_x so we can do it again
            go_x = True
            break
```

here is my stop() for context:

```
def stop():
    global go_x
    go_x = False
    ...
```

and the button call to stop()

```
stop_all=Button(window, text="Stop", fg='red', command=stop)
```

Comment: You don't need to check `go_x` in your loop.  It's always going to be true, and when you set it to False, you exit the loop.  In fact, you could use `while True:` here, since you always break.

Comment: You're overwriting the parameter `target` without looking at its original value.

Comment: @TimRoberts I originally tried it without go_x but my stop() didn't work well. I have added the stop function and button call for context

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

# Constants
TOLERANCE = 0.1  # Adjust this tolerance as needed
ROUND_DECIMALS = 2

def go_to_position_x(target):
    target = float(go_to_x.get())  # Input from tkinter app
    tolerance = TOLERANCE
    timeout = 60  # Set a timeout in seconds

    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        window.update()  # Update the tkinter window
        position_x = round(read_once(), ROUND_DECIMALS)

        if abs(position_x - target) <= tolerance:
            stop_x(target)
            print("Move x done")
            break

        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            print("Timeout reached. Aborting move.")
            break

        if position_x < target:
            stop_x_reverse(target)
            run_x(target)
        elif position_x > target:
            stop_x(target)
            run_x_reverse(target)
        else:
            stop()
            print("Got to else and stop")
            break
```

Some Tips:

1. Break down your code into smaller functions.
2. Instead of using a global variable like go_x, consider passing it as
   a parameter to your functions
3. Instead of constantly updating the tkinter window using
   window.update(), you can use time.sleep to introduce a small delay
4. Instead of using hard-coded values like 2 for rounding or True for
   comparisons, consider using constants or named variables

Comment: thank you, but if I use this my stop button doesn't work anymore. If I use the go_x global then it kind of works but I need to press the Stop button multiple times before it works. In my original code I was able to only haev to press the Stop button once.

```def stop():
    global go_x
    go_x = False
    ...
```
I edited my post to show more context

Comment: your code is a lot more precise than mine was, thank you

Comment: the Timeout feature is nice but it doesn't work, I think because the move is already running. It actually breaks out of the loop and the motor runs away. The move functions are just calls to Digital Output signals and a reverse move is done with a polarity change. These particular motors are either on or off, which is why I'm using a PLC to handle the motion and analog input.

Comment: So you propose two variables, TOLERANCE and tolerance?  I'd argue this is an anti-pattern.   Since TOLERANCE is not updated, just refer to the global and avoid creating needless variables.